# Creating a browser front-end for TigerLogic D3 DB application

Tags: web-services, web-applications, browser, multivalue-database, pick

I have an interesting conundrum. I have been challenged with identifying the most suitable process in which to create a "browser front-end" to an existing multi-user application built within the TigerLogic/Pick D3 environment. My research indicates there are many ways to do this; but I am struggling to decide which method is best or where to start. I have "played" with a few technologies but a commitment to one is needed to get started.

These methods include:

- Creation of a complex webservice using MVS Toolkit; and engineering a client from WSDL either from scratch or using maven/wsimport. Tests indicate there is a lot more to this process than originally though for a simply WSDL.
- Development of a Java based web app that harnesses the MVSPJavaAPI - I am not a JAVA developer so this means learning a new language. Development would most likely take place in Eclipse.
- Using TigerLogics FlashCONNECT - resulting in additional expenditure to clients so not preferable - and more or less ruled
  out.

There is also the .NET option - but I have ruled this out on the basis of needing portability.

My question is, has anyone else out there done anything like this and could you share your experience? My first task is to build a web-app that will reliably give me the D3 TCL prompt in a browser that I can customise.

I am not sure there is a definitive answer here but would like peoples thoughts and will label the most useful as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What path you choose depends in some part on your existing skill-set and whether that fits in with your portability needs. It is very difficult to give you a concrete answer to your question becaue of not knowing in which part of the chain you need the portability.

It is however possible to develop a web-browser front-end using .NET which will run on Linux or Windows, so I don't see an issue with portability here. Your web server will have to be windows based but it shouldn't matter whether D3 is running on Linux or Windows at the server-end, or whether the client desktops are running Linux or Windows.

You could try TigerLogics MVSP .NET API but I do not know if it has the power to deliver based on your needs. I believe you may find [mv.NET from Bluefinity](http://www.bluefinity.com/site/mvnet.html) could fulfill your needs. This is in my opinion the leading product on the MultiValue market for achieving the goals you have in mind. This will mean spending money of course. For this you will get a very powerful set of tools. Also, the cost of investing in a good tool could end up smaller than the cost in terms of time, effort and potential complications of trying to do this piecemeal **without** spending any extra money. I am sure Flashconnect would also do the job. You would have to weigh up the cost of the different options to find out which one is right for you both technically and financially.

Not knowing whether or not you have .NET in your skill-set, I don't know whether the .NET option would be easier for you. It is however technically possible.

Comment: Thanks for your input Glenn. Our D3 installations are primarily Linux (CENTOS) based and I would like the webservers to be running on the same machine... so everything is neat and users can just jump on through a browser using a dedicated port. Hence ruling out .NET.

Comment: Glenn do you have any opinions on MVS Toolkit / WSDL option?

Comment: Also, I am not keen on the prospect of being heavily MS reliant - hence the browser front end strategy.

Comment: It sounds as if FlashConnect could be your best option then. I would sleep more easily keeping D3 server and Web Server on seperate machines. I would be intrigued to hear what you decide. (Sent before seeing your last two comments!)

Comment: With respect to your comment about being too MS reliant, perhaps using Mono along with the TL .NET API or MV.NET would be an option. However, I would be pushing on the borders of my knowledge there!

Comment: Regarding MVS Toolkit. It is free of charge if you are on maintenance contract with TigerLogic so this would fit the finance criteria.

Comment: I have played with MVS TK to create very basic webservices and WSDL's. These have proven difficult to create working clients from which should not be the case. Leading me back to JAVA which, again, is a whole new language and widely discouraged in the creation of modern web apps.

Comment: Before seeing the last comment here I just wrote a long Answer that included Java options. Sigh. As already mentioned perhaps it would be best if you could list the skills which are already available as well as those which the company/client might be inclined to commission if required. Given that we might be able to point you toward a solution that can be used more readily.

@Glenn, I'm fond of Mono but I don't believe the MVSP .NET library can be used through Mono over *nix. Rocket can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Rocket's D3 (formerly TigerLogic D3) .NET APIs and create a Web API RESTful service that you can consume with JavaScript in any other web technology and if you need to call from a D3 subroutine (in case you would) then use the MVS Toolkit.

Requirements though are D3 9.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I've used all of the technologies described, and many more to interface with D3. I agree with @Glenn and will add... I understand you're edging away from .NET. That's fine, you don't need it. But consider that most LAMP implementations separate the DBMS servers from the web servers. That topology introduces short delays between the tiers but decouples them in case you want to use multiple web servers or multiple databases - a common topology even with D3 / MV.

I have a client where we have a Java/Grails front-end over Linux, with all data queries filtered through a single, elegant data provider class that's abstracted from application logic. That uses a web service call which I wrote in Java, calling to a .NET web service. The service is easily generated/modified, as is the client from the WSDL. From there IIS carries inbound queries to D3 via mv.NET, and at this point it doesn't matter if the D3 DBMS is in Linux or Windows. My web service could have as easily been in Linux with Java but it would then lack a pooling mechanism - see below.

If you want all Linux then you can go with the MVSP Java library. TigerLogic (now acquired by Rocket Software) committed to a PHP binding for MVSP some months ago. Rather than wait, one of my clients created a PHP wrapper around mv.NET, though MVSP is as easy. So the resulting application is essentially LAMP, but with the M = Multivalue. I have written code like this too - we can write a wrapper in any language which exposes a useful API and abstracts both connectivity method and OS dependencies. In other words it doesn't matter what languages we want to use or what OS's are involved. That part is rather trivial and subject to change later. It's better to focus on the application than the communications.

You can also go off the menu, so to speak, and create your own Java/PHP wrapper around the OS-level d3tcl command, which is a script/wrapper around the d3 executable. This allows you to open a connection yourself and pass in commands.

Whatever option you select, you need to consider that opening and closing a DBMS connection is a slow process. You do not want to script a login around every data request. You do want to open a connection and keep that open persistently, while your client code accesses and releases that persistent connection as required. This is why we like mv.NET and FlashCONNECT. With MVSP and other mechanisms you need to create your own persistence model. You'll also need to manage a pool of connection resources - what happens when you get 10 simultaneous queries, or just 1 short one after one long one? You don't want queries to back up, you don't want to reject or timeout connections, and you don't want to fire up a connection for every client. You do want the proper number of DBMS sessions waiting for inbound connections. mv.NET and FlashCONNECT do this for you, the others do not.

Personally I'd shy away from FlashCONNECT. I was there for its initial development and testing and for years of end-user implementations. It's not as widely used as the other options and is more a tool for those who aren't familiar with other options. If you're talking about Java then you're probably not inclined to use FlashCONNECT. That said, if you have developers who are not familiar with anything outside D3 then FlashCONNECT is a decent server-side tool for them while someone else is focusing on the client-side with other technologies. Everyone should use their best skillset.

Finally, (already?) if someone is not familiar with external technologies, and more intimate with D3, then other options exist like DesignBAIS and Viságe, mostly removing the burden of communications and allowing developers to work on the client-side features and back-end rules in BASIC.

I discuss all of these topics plus mobile and telephony on [my blog](http://Nebula-RnD.com/blog).

HTH